# Inserting field which is both PrimaryKey and DEFAULT using gorm to MySQL

Tags: mysql, go, go-gorm

I want to have a table whose primary key is an auto-generated timestamp (I know it's generally not the best idea, but in my case it's OK) and it has another string field. This is the data structure that I use:

```
type GlobalDefault struct {
    Timestamp       time.Time           `gorm:"primary_key" sql:"DEFAULT:current_timestamp"`
    Version         string              `sql:"not null"`
}
```

When I use this data structure with AutoMigrate I indeed get a table with the timestamp as primary key, and I can even run `insert into global_defaults (version) VALUES ('1.5.3');` and a new row would get inserted with an auto-generated timestamp.

My problem is that I can't insert records into this table using gorm. I use the following function:

```
func (repository *AgentRepository)SetGlobalDefault(version string) error {
    gd := GlobalDefault{ Version:version }
    return repository.connection.Create(&gd).Error
}
```

And when I call it I get the following error:

> Received unexpected error could not convert argument of field Timestamp from int64 to time.Time

If I provide the timestamp explicitly, it works. I'm guessing that it has a problem with the default time ('0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC') which is created when I don't specify it exactly.

Is there a way around this?

Comment: My advice not to use Timestamp as primary key in MySQL. It cannot be guaranteed to be unique, it could cause [trouble](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=8523) for you in MySQL; because timestamps are stored with only 1-second precision. 

Use BIGINT for primary key and add index to Timestamp column.

Comment: I know, and I wrote that in my question. But my focus is understanding how to use gorm. If I know how to create such a schema using SQL I want to understand how to do it using gorm.

Answer (score 0):

After comment interaction, drafting this answer.

> I'm guessing that it has a problem with the default time ('0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC') which is created when I don't specify it exactly.

The reason is, in Go data type has zero value, [spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec#The_zero_value) and good read [here](https://dave.cheney.net/2013/01/19/what-is-the-zero-value-and-why-is-it-useful).

For you, possible way is to use appropriate [gorm callbacks](http://jinzhu.me/gorm/callbacks.html) to set or modify struct fields on before or after database interactions.